# Why does the code still print the string to the other file when I saw the code run through correctly?

Tags: c

I debugged it carefully and I saw the code ran through this command

```
else if (vowel == smallv)
{
    fprintf (tempfilesmall, "\n%s",str);
}
```

But actually the code printf something to tempfilebig instead

My input is :

```
happy good bad bad bad
bad bad
hehe
```

the 'bad' is supposed to print to the temp-small-value file, instead it printed to the temp-big-value file. 
This is very strange, does anyone know what happened?

```
tempfilebig = freopen ("tempbig.txt","w",stdout);
tempfilesmall = freopen ("tempsmall.txt","w",stdout);
```

Comment: @WeatherVane You can see the snippet now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`freopen` return value is the stream, in this case `stdout`. So you actually overwrite your `FILE` pointer with it in these lines:

```
tempfilebig = freopen ("tempbig.txt","w",stdout);
tempfilesmall = freopen ("tempsmall.txt","w",stdout);
```

Since you want to bascially clear these files and reopening them, then do this

```
tempfilebig = freopen ("tempbig.txt","w",tempfilebig);
tempfilesmall = freopen ("tempsmall.txt","w",tempfilesmall);
```

Comment: Which means I should ignore the "tempfilesmall =" before the "freopen ("tempsmall.txt","w",stdout)" ?

Comment: @MichaelCruz Yes but after that you will realize then these lines do nothing, since they essentially redirect stdout to your file, but you do not write anything to the stdout so they are pointless after all.

Comment: what i really wanted to do is to use the freopen to clear the things already in the tempsmall, so I can write the new value for it.

Comment: Then keep the lines and replace stdout with the FILE pointer variable. Edited the answer to reflect this